# Remove focus on textbox in Ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many text boxes in a page and all are disabled on init.In Ipad only,(Safari and chrome)on page load the focus comes automatically on the fourth text box.

I removed that text box then focus comes on the 3rd one and so forth.
Since that textbox is disabled,you can see the textbox highlighted on init.When you click anywhere on the screen then a keyboard pops up for a half a second and then closes.

I dont want the focus to be on the textbox on init.It can be at the dropdown(optional) or no focus at all.

In ipad safari,textbox is highlighted and on clicking anywhere on screen keyboard opens.

In ipad chrome,there is focus and keyboard popup on init itself.
How can i prevent this.

use jquery/javascript

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of `focus` is `blur`. You can just call this to remove `focus` from all inputs:

```
$("input").blur();
```

Or as you said, if you want to have focus on your `select` instead, just give the `focus` to this element. It should remove the focus from the `input` then.

```
// change the selector to your exact 'select' element
$("select").focus();
```

Comment: That didnt work out.Already had tried that.There are 40 textboxes and 40 checkboxes in 10 rows,like one row is for parameter mean with 4 individual text & checkboxes.This row is visible conditionally fom user settings of which parameter he wants.Initailly they are all disabled.All textboxes are disabled on init and are eanbled on checkbox tick.The focus comes on Mean parameters 2nd textbox on init.If i remove that parameter from settings,then focus comes on next textbox.They all are disabled.
I've used focus(),blur(),tabindex doesnt work.
Only reproduced in Ipad